# How do I grant lfs full access to all directories when setting up Linux From Scratch with Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: command-line, bash, vmware, 22.04

I am following [Linux From Scratch (LFS)](https://linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/) on Ubuntu 22.04. And at one point it says:

> Grant lfs full access to all directories under $LFS by making lfs the directory owner:

```sh
chown -v lfs $LFS/{usr{,/*},lib,var,etc,bin,sbin,tools}
case $(uname -m) in
  x86_64) chown -v lfs $LFS/lib64 ;;
esac
```

`lfs` is the user and `LFS` is `/mnt/lfs` path. I used the script and output was:

```
ownership of '/usr' retained as lfs
ownership of '/usr/bin' retained as lfs
ownership of '/usr/games' retained as lfs
ownership of '/usr/include' retained as lfs
ownership of '/usr/lib' retained as lfs
ownership of '/usr/lib32' retained as lfs
ownership of '/usr/lib64' retained as lfs
ownership of '/usr/libexec' retained as lfs
ownership of '/usr/libx32' retained as lfs
ownership of '/usr/local' retained as lfs
ownership of '/usr/sbin' retained as lfs
ownership of '/usr/share' retained as lfs
ownership of '/usr/src' retained as lfs
ownership of '/lib' retained as lfs
ownership of '/var' retained as lfs
ownership of '/etc' retained as lfs
ownership of '/bin' retained as lfs
ownership of '/sbin' retained as lfs
chown: cannot access '/tools': No such file or directory
failed to change ownership of '/tools' to lfs
ownership of '/lib64' retained as lfs
```

I thought it will grant access under /mnt/lfs but output says another. Are there any problem or is it ok?

Edit: I think i couldnt ask my question properly. I dont ask why i coldnt get ownership of `/tools`. I am asking why these codes trying to get ownership of root dirs of my system when it says it will get ownership of directories under the `/mnt/lfs` AKA `$LFS` dir.

Isnt `$LFS/{usr{,/*},lib,var,etc,bin,sbin,tools` means something like

```
/mnt/lfs/usr
/mnt/lfs/lib
/mnt/lfs/etc
...
```

But it tries to get ownership directly for

```
/usr
/lib
/etc
...
```

`/tools` dir not the point of this question.

Comment: i think it tries for directly /tools directory. Same for others. But quote says its for `$LFS` directories.

Comment: You tried to work on `$LFS/tools`, but if `$LFS` is empty, you are destroying your file system. Doesn't look like an Ubuntu-related question.

Comment: Your command works ... `ownership of '/usr' retained as lfs` means the directory is already owned by the same user `lfs` so no need to change it ... one directory however is non-existent `chown: cannot access '/tools': No such file or directory`.

Comment: I would do this on a container/virtual machine.  `LFS=""; ls -ld $LFS/{usr{,/*},lib,var,etc,bin,sbin,tools}` return a similar output, should show root:root on a normal installation

Comment: Most of these dirs are not there under `$LFS`. `ls` in `/mnt/lfs` path: `etc  lost+found  sources  tools  usr  var`. I thought it will get ownership for `mnt/lfs/usr`, `mnt/lfs/usr/bin` and so on. I know these dirs not exist in `$LFS`. But it looks command get directly `/usr`, `/usr/bin` and other dirs ownerships. Im on virtual machine by the way.

Comment: I should warn you, however, that what your doing is very destructive to your file system.

Comment: In which section of [the manual](https://linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/) you are? There is a huge difference if you remove the starting slash on `etc` or `mnt` dirs.

Comment: It is [lfs-ch4](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter04/addinguser.html)

Comment: ... perhaps you skipped [2.6. Setting The $LFS Variable](https://linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter02/aboutlfs.html) ?

Comment: The title is not helpful at all to attract people having a similar issue (which seems related to [this step, _Setting The $LFS Variable_](https://www.linuxfromscratch.org/lfs/view/stable/chapter02/aboutlfs.html)). Either way, this is an LFS question, is not related in any way to Ubuntu (or any host distro).

Comment: Guys i am not asking LFS question. I am asking shell question. Is is that hard to see that? i set the variable. @steeldriver i added the variable to .bashrc but now i checked and it is not there. i was getting `echo $LFS : /mnt/lfs` but now it just gives empty output. Finally an worthy answer. Yeah my fault thx.